# Manage Date in a Reservation System

Tags: mysql, database

Hi guys i'm creating a simple web application in Java in which i should book a room. Now my problem concerns the possibility of booking a room in the same period.
Let me explain better, I have 2 types of rooms, bedroom1 and bedroom2. If user1 has booked room1 on 22/08/2018, user2 can not book room1 on the same date.
Since I use a database I thought I could solve it by query.
In particular my database:

> Table Name: reservation
>
> id_book,login,email,typeroom,numroom,arrivaldate,departuredate.

I have tried to use this query:

```
SELECT res1.id_prenotazione, res1.typeroom, res1.arrivaldate, res1.departuredate
FROM reservation res1, reservation res2
WHERE ( res1.typeroom = res2.typeroom ) AND (res1.arrivaldate = res2.arrivaldate )
```

But I don't resolve the problem.
Can you help me??

UPDATE.

```
try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
      //  out.println("driver loaded");
            Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Hotel?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","root" ,"123456789");
            out.println("Connect");
            Statement  st =  con.createStatement();
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            out.println("connection successfull");
            
            String check = ("SELECT res1.id_prenotazione, res1.typeroom, res1.arrivaldate, res1.departuredate\n" + 
                    "FROM reservation res1, reservation res2\n" + 
                    "WHERE res1.numroom = res2.numroom\n" + 
                    "AND ((res1.arrivaldate <= res2.departuredate AND res1.departuredate >= res2.arrivaldate)\n" + 
                    "  OR (res2.arrivaldate <= res1.departuredate AND res2.departuredate >= res1.arrivaldate))");
            
            ResultSet rs2  = stmt.executeQuery(check);
            int rs =  st.executeUpdate("insert into reservation (login,email,typeroom,numroom,arrivaldate,departuredate)values ('"+login+"','"+email+"','"+typeroom+"','"+numroom+"','"+arrivaldate+"','"+departuredate+"')");
```

I'm trying first to use the database version of your answer. I have write this, to check if the booking is ok or not i should insert an if controller?

Comment: "But nothing change" - what is supposed to change relative to what? Note that if your database covers more than one day per room, you need to design a query that checks **overlap** of dates, not equality.

Comment: @RealSkeptic you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean overlap of reservations for the same room:

```
SELECT res1.id_prenotazione, res1.typeroom, res1.arrivaldate, res1.departuredate
FROM reservation res1, reservation res2
WHERE res1.room_no = res2.room_no
AND res1.id_prenotazione != res2.id_prenotazione
AND res1.arrivaldate <= res2.departuredate AND res1.departuredata >= res2.arrivaldate
```

What should maybe checked too is: you used date equality. If that failed, maybe your table columns are not DATE but DATETIME/TIMESTAMP. That would be understandable
as someone might leave his room at 9:00 and the next enter at say 12:00.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yes forgotten to check that records are different. The OR-condition checks for the two overlaps: `[ { ] }` versus `{ [ } ]` (switched res1 with res2). - Overlaps will be listed twice.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - I am bowing. Totally right, and in fact I did ranges (in programming language, not in SQL) and I cannot remember that much code. I'll correct.

Answer (score 0):

`AND (res1.arrivaldate = res2.arrivaldate )` would be wrong. You need a range
e.g `AND (res1.arrivaldate > res2.arrivaldate ) AND (res1.arrivaldate < res2.departuredate)` or something similar

Answer (score 0):

If you want overlapping periods:

```
SELECT res1.id_prenotazione, res1.typeroom, res1.arrivaldate, res1.departuredate
FROM reservation res1, reservation res2
WHERE ( res1.typeroom = res2.typeroom ) 
AND res1.id_book != res2.id_book
AND (res1.arrivaldate <= res2.departuredate)
AND (res2.arrivaldate <= res1.departuredate)
```

Comment: You need an extra condition, to make sure that `res1` and `res2` aren't referring to the same reservation.

Comment: You are completely right! I updated the answer.